# Urban Airship: Can I tag scheduled notifications?

Tags: objective-c, ios, urbanairship.com

I'm using Urban Airship to handle my push notifications. In my application people can schedule notifications for soccer matches. Lets say the match has been canceled. Then I would like to cancel all the scheduled notifications for that match, for all users.

If I could tag the scheduled notifications with the "match id" I could delete all the notifications with the "match id" tag.

However, the documentation say's nothing about tagging scheduled notifications. Can it be done, or can I do it in some other way? I figure this must be a rather common situation. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

How are you triggering the notification in the first place?

I find it's best to think of Urban Airship as sort of a three layer push system:

1) User layer (Iphone, Android, Tablet)
2) Urban Airship layer (Your account on Urban Airship that is linked to Apple push servers or GCM)
3) Server layer (A web server where you keep user information from layer 1)

In this system, your web server (layer 3) is responsible for storing data about each of your users (layer 1). When your user signs in to your app, you store that users' Urban Airship app id/token on your server. Your server layer is also responsible for initiating pushes to Urban Airship, and eventually to the device. Because you control your server layer, you control when pushes get initiated and when not to initiate a push (In the case that a match is canceled for instance).

1. There is a match on and it's time to send a notification to all of your users that signed up for an alert for this particular match
2. Your server already has a list of all the individual users that have noted their interest in this game.
3. For each of the users, your server tells Urban Airship that you want to send a notification.
4. Urban Airship does the heavy lifting for you and makes sure the notification makes it to each device.
5. Your user rejoices because they were reminded about the game.

I'm not even sure this helps you, it's possible you don't have a server layer and are trying to do this from either just the device or just Urban Airship. In that case, I would say that you are probably limited in what you are able to do with either platform. Good luck!